# Was Edwin Abbott trying to make fun of Christianity in this part of Flatland?

Tags: edwin-abbott-abbott, flatland

Chapter 21 of the second edition of *Flatland* contains the following quote:

> I AWOKE rejoicing, and began to reflect on the glorious career before me. I would go forth, methought, at once, and **evangelize** the whole of Flatland. Even to Women and Soldiers should the **Gospel** of Three Dimensions be proclaimed. I would begin with my Wife.

The text contains numerous references like this.

What's the author's point in referring to this as a Gospel, and speaking of evangelizing and making converts? Is he intending to parody Christianity here and, if so, why?

Comment: It seems to me that his meaning is that this new information is supremely important, nigh unto a religion, and thus he uses words with religious connotations, to emphasize the idea that it is now his sacred duty to spread this information, with zeal and dedication like that of a missionary.  The word choice indicates "this is basically my religion now".